# How to programatically/dynamically define route transitions in liquid fire (ember.js)?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, routes

If there are two buttons on the screen inside a box/view and if user clicks left button, the box should transition to the left whereas if the user clicks right button the box should transition to the right. How to do that ?

There is an issue raised here about it: https://github.com/ef4/liquid-fire/issues/95

Basically what I can already do is this:

```
 this.transition(
    this.fromRoute('foo'),
    this.toRoute('bar'),
    this.use('toLeft', { duration: 500 }),
    this.reverse('toRight', { duration: 500 })
    );
```

But what I want to do is this:

```
 this.transition(
    this.fromRoute('foo'),
    this.toRoute('bar'),
    this.hasClass('move-left'), // if true transition to left (this class is inside of {{link-to }} helper
    this.use('toLeft', { duration: 500 }),
    this.reverse('toRight', { duration: 500 })
    );    

  this.transition(
    this.fromRoute('foo'),
    this.toRoute('bar'),
    this.hasClass('move-right'), // if true transition to right (this class is inside of {{link-to }} helper
    this.use('toRight', { duration: 500 }),
    this.reverse('toLeft', { duration: 500 })
    );
```

or this:

```
 this.transition(
    this.fromRoute('foo'),
    this.toRoute('bar'),
    this.toModel(function(){ return this.get('q41') === 'left' })
    this.use('toLeft', { duration: 500 }),
    this.reverse('toRight', { duration: 500 })
    );    

  this.transition(
    this.fromRoute('foo'),
    this.toRoute('bar'),
    this.toModel(function(){ return this.get('q41') === 'right' })
    this.use('toRight', { duration: 500 }),
    this.reverse('toLeft', { duration: 500 })
    );
```

Is it possible to apply certain transition/animation to a route in Ember only of certain conditions are met (i.e. specific {{link-to}} helper has been clicked or certain data in the model has been recorded (which {{link-to}} helper has been clicked on is being recorded).

The problem I get is that liquid fire cant get the model and its properties.